# Questions on some code using boost::zip_iterator

Tags: c++, boost

Recently I saw some example code on how to use boost::zip_iterator. However, I can't figure out how it works. Here is the code:

```
class to_hex2
{
private:
    vector<unsigned char> &v;
    char trans(const char c) const
    {
        if(c >= 'a')
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        else if(c >= 'A')
            return c - 'A' + 10;
        else
            return c - '0';
    }
public:
    to_hex2(vector<unsigned char> &_v): 
        v(_v){}

    typedef boost::tuples::tuple<const char&,const char&> Tuple;
    void operator()(Tuple const &t) const   
    {
        static char tmp;    
        tmp = trans(t.get<0>()) * 0x10;
        tmp += trans(t.get<1>());
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
};

int main()
{
    char s[] = "1234aBcD";
    vector<unsigned char> v;
    typedef step_iterator<const char*> si_t;    
    for_each(
                boost::make_zip_iterator(
                    boost::tuples::make_tuple(si_t(s),si_t(s+1))),  
                boost::make_zip_iterator(
                    boost::tuples::make_tuple(si_t(s+8),si_t(s+9))),    
                to_hex2(v));
    std::copy(
                v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(cout," "));
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"v.size="<<v.size();
    return 0;
}
```

**step_iterator** is an iterator that iterates two steps instead of one.

My first question is: Is it OK to write s+9 since the index of array s is up to 8(including '\0':-) )? The code seems to run properly although.

My second question is: Since zip_iterator makes it possible to iterate over a vector concurrently, does that mean the result is random? The result I see is constant, in the following picture:
[image]

Last but not least, could someone please tell me how is the result generated( what's the meaning of it) since there is no up-down arrow in ASCII codes( I googled it and saw it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_%28symbol%29)).

Comment: An array has N-1 elements, so if you dereference the Nth element you'll get **undefined behaviour**. ` `boost::tuples::make_tuple(si_t(s+8),si_t(s+9)))` this is undefined behaviour, your array is only 8 long, meaning element 8 is not accessible and element 9 is lala land and out of your reach.

Comment: To correct what @TonyTheLion said: it is legal to point anywhere in an array, and dereference the pointer; it is legal to point one past the end of an array, but dereferencing such pointer is undefined behavior; pointing anywhere else is undefined behavior, even if the pointer is never dereferenced. So `char *p = s + 9` is ok as long as you don't dereference `p`, but `p = s + 10` would be undefined behavior. Therefore, this is code is valid wrt pointers.

Comment: @LucTouraille the array here is size 8, so N-1 is the last actual element.  Isn't 8 then the one past the end of the array?

Comment: @Tony: no, the array size is 9. It is initialized from a string literal, which is null-terminated (`s[8] = '\0'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to point one-past-the-end of an array, as long as you don't dereference the pointer. This is very useful because C++ uses half-open ranges, where the last element is excluded.

In the code you posted, `s+9` points one-past-the-end of s, but is never dereferenced, so the behavior is well-defined.

Regarding your second question: no, the result of this code is not random. The elements will be iterated over in order, from first to last. When the documentation states that `zip_iterator` allows parallel iteration over a sequence, it does not mean that the iteration will be performed concurrently by several threads or whatever, it only means that each iteration will advance several iterators instead of only one. Here is a possible implementation of `for_each`:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename Func>
void for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Func f)
{
    while (first != last)
    {
        f(*first);
        ++first;
    }
}
```

As you see, `for_each` works on a single iterator. If you need to iterate over two sequences at a time, then you can use `zip_iterator`, which encapsulates several iterators. Its `operator*` returns multiple values (a tuple), and its `operator++`s increments all the iterators, advancing them simultaneously.

To better understand what is going on in your code, here is a streamlined version, without `zip_iterator` and `for_each`:

```
class to_hex2
{
private:
    vector<unsigned char> &v;
    char trans(const char c) const
    {
        if(c >= 'a')
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        else if(c >= 'A')
            return c - 'A' + 10;
        else
            return c - '0';
    }
public:
    to_hex2(vector<unsigned char> &_v): 
        v(_v){}

    void operator()(const char &first, const char &second) const   
    {
        static char tmp;    
        tmp = trans(first) * 0x10;
        tmp += trans(second);
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
};

int main()
{
    char s[] = "1234aBcD";
    vector<unsigned char> v;

    to_hex2 transformer(v);

    char *first = s;
    char *second = s + 1;

    for ( ; first != s + 8 && second != s + 9 ; first += 2, second += 2)
    {
        transformer(*first, *second);
    }

    std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(cout," "));
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"v.size="<<v.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, this should make it clear that `zip_iterator` is just a convenient way of making several iterators advance at the same time.

Finally, to understand the purpose of this code, you should probably print the result as integers rather than as characters. You should see this:

```
18 52 171 205
```

which are the decimal representation of the hexadecimal numbers contained in the original string (`12`<sub>16</sub> = `18`<sub>10</sub>, `34`<sub>16</sub> = `52`<sub>10</sub>, `AB`<sub>16</sub> = `171`<sub>10</sub> and `CD`<sub>16</sub> = `205`<sub>10</sub>). So basically, `v` contains the representation in base 256 of the original hexadecimal string.

Comment: It is very kind of you to explain in such detail. Finally I got the meaning of this code. Thanks!